# What is the minimum version of Samba that will connect to a Windows Server 2008 domain controller?

Tags: samba

(Yes, I know I need to upgrade to a considerably more modern version of Samba.  Assume that's not feasible right now for a variety of reasons.)

Assuming Windows Server 2008 (or R2) is the AD Domain Controller, what is the oldest version of Samba that can connect to it?

I have some old Linux servers, running 3.0.25+ versions of Samba, that have been quite happily connecting to a Win 2003 DC.  Obviously that's no longer an option.  What's the minimum I have to do to get them working for now? I see some things that say 3.5, others that say 3.0.21c, others that say 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your SMB settings on your Domain Controllers. Win 2008 is before SMB2 became a thing, so you don't have to worry about that. [What you do have to worry about is the "LAN Manager authentication level" setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level).

**LM & NTLM**: The 2.x series had this.
**NTLMv2**: Support improved over time, was stable in the 3.1 series

The other setting people get worried over is if you're requiring SMB Signing. Samba added that feature in the 3.0 series, so you probably already have it.

Answer (score 0):

To work as a domain controller, you will need version 4.0 of the Samba, or greater than 4.0.